# draw multipart polygon with one surrounding border

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, spatialite, filling

As you can see on the image below, the waterbody is divided by the border line because it consists of several polygons.

[image]

I could merge the polygon, but I dont want to change the shapefile. 
Is there a option in QGIS to draw te waterbody just with a border sourrounding its "absolute extend"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the style of your layer, on the top right there is the type of rule to apply when 'virtually" merging objects of the same layer. Select "dodge" in the drop down menu. (sorry if the terms are not exact but my qgis is not in English, I will edit the post when I get to another computer)

Comment: Right! but its not "addition" its "dodge". Its working!

Comment: corrected (in french it worked with "addition")